# Select query with where clause in node.js - mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, validation, casting

Here In this API I fetch records using select query and In where clause which `folderid's` match that record I want to fetch. `req.body.folderid is 1024wioqdwwb` but in folder table `folderid is 1024` so that record is fetched but i dont want that record. `folderid datatype is int`

```
app.post('/getFolderDetails',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body.folderid); //1024wioqdwwb

  connection.query("SELECT folderid,folderName FROM folder WHERE folderid = ?", [req.body.folderid] , function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results); // [ RowDataPacket { folderid: 1024, folderName :'folder-1' } ]
    res.send({  
      'status':'1',
      'success':'true',
      'payload': results,
   });      
 });
})
```

folder table

```
folderid    folderName
 1024         folder-1
 1025         folder-2
 1026         folder-3
 1027         folder-4
```

Comment: `req.body.folderid is 1024wioqdwwb` ...sounds like the data is being submitted incorrectly and not validated. So the issue isn't really in the query, it's in the application code / form which is calling it. If folderID is `int` then you should be validating that the input data is also `int`. Otherwise you cannot be sure your code will run as you expect.

Comment: if your req.body.folderid is 1024, it will fetch your record. Error in front end side, please validate.

Comment: The query still returns a row because when it sees the string `1024wioqdwwb` and compares it to the int value in the DB, because the string happens to start with a number, it simply takes all the characters from the string until the first non-integer character and uses that as the comparison value. In other words it first truncates the string to `'1024'`, the casts that to an integer `1024` and then compares that to the values in the table. So that's why it still returns a result. You say you don't want this row returned...ok, but why are you allowing such nonsense input to begin with?

Comment: @ADyson I understand

Comment: @MohamedSameer it still returns the record now, even with that string. That's OP's point - they don't want that. See my comment above to understand why. But yes, I agree the front-end should not be allowing such nonsensical input in the first place.

Comment: On top of what ADyson said, why are you looking for '1024wioqdwwb' when folderid datatype is int????

Comment: @nazim True but that's not on top of what I said, that's exactly what I already said :-)

Comment: :P in 'short and sweet'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query still returns a row because of what happens when it sees the string `1024wioqdwwb` and compares it to the int value in the DB:

Because the string happens to start with a number, it simply takes all the characters from the string until the first non-integer character and uses that as the comparison value.

In other words it first truncates the string to `'1024'`, then casts that to an integer `1024` and then compares that to the values in the table. And course `1024` matches the id `1024` in the table, so that's why it still returns a result.

You say you don't want this row returned...ok, but why are you allowing such nonsense input to begin with? I think the issue is not with your query, but with the (lack of) validation of the input values in your application. That's where you need to change your code. Unfortunately we can't see that code so we can't give you specific advice about it, but that would be my recommendation.

Comment: ADyson can you give me solution in node before connection.query if characters in req,body.folderid then directy sent in else condition and not allow to fetch query

Comment: @Ankit Sorry I'm knowlegeable about SQL and about application development principles in general (e.g. knowing the importance of correct input validation), but I've never used NodeJS so I don't know the specifics of how you would validate the input - other than doing a simple manual JS type check, which would be fine but a bit of a quick-and-dirty solution.

Comment: @Ankit But I expect a more sophisticated and generic validation approach can be taken if you do a [little bit of research](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=CH4bXJHxMM2l1fAP6Nu36AE&q=nodeJS+input+validation&oq=nodeJS+input+validation&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i7i30l2j0i8i7i10i30j0i8i13i30.8558.9031..9160...0.0..1.181.516.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30.7zpTzTpNKQQ) . Then you have a framework to validate all inputs to your app. Input validation is a vital part of any application, especially web-based ones which are much more open to mis-use by outsiders.

Comment: I done validation frontend and backend bothsides, thank you ADyson for your help